# I want to get all the values in an object with a same field name and store in an array

Tags: javascript

I have this object and I want to get only a specific value in object
input

```
var lst = [
  {
    name: "foo", 
    value: "fooValue"
  }, 
  {
    name: "bar", 
    value: "barValue"
  }
];
```

output:

```
var b = ["foo", "bar"];
```

Comment: No, you don't want *a specific value*, rather all values under a **specific property name**. Your question title is better than the description :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var lst = [
  {
    name: "foo", 
    value: "fooValue"
  }, 
  {
    name: "bar", 
    value: "barValue"
  }
];

var b = lst.map(ob => ob.name);

console.log( b )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var lst = [{name: "foo", value: "fooValue"},{name: "bar",value: "barValue"}];

var output = lst.map(({name}) => name);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do this often, it might help to make a reusable function out of this.  A common name for this operation is `pluck`.

```js
const pluck = (prop) => (xs) => xs.map(x => x[prop])

const lst = [{name: "foo", value: "fooValue"}, {name: "bar", value: "barValue"}]

const allNames = pluck('name')
console.log(allNames(lst));

// or just

console.log(pluck('name')(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object destructuring` to simply pull out the value you're looking to append to your array.

```
array.forEach(({name}) =>  b.push(name));
```

```js
var b = [], lst = [{name: "foo",value: "fooValue"},{name: "bar",value: "barValue"}]
.forEach(({name}) =>  b.push(name));


console.log(b);
```